# Error parsing XML unbound prefix line 5

Tags: android, xml

i get an error in my android code....what am i doing wrong here?..thanks

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
            <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:title="Search"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
         andorid:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchActionProvider"
         app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
          app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" 
         app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchActionProvider" />
         </menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo in `andorid:actionProviderClass`. Should be `android:actionProviderClass`.